# Android studio CSV file size limit

Tags: android-studio, csv, kotlin

I have an dictionary.csv in my assets folder. I can't able to display all the rows in my android app cause the file size is 9.56 MB but limit size is 2.56 How to increase that in android studio.

I want to display the whole file in my app, I try to use SQLITE database file for dictionary but its more complicated, if someone knew how to extend the csv file limit in android studio or any other ways to display the large size file means tell me. And am using kotlin to develop my android app.